# Citing style for Animal Conservation

Tags: citations, citation-style

I am writing a commentary paper in Animal Conservation magazine. I have a hard time to find out a reference manager that will produce the right citing style

I read for their [guidelines to authors](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/journal/10.1111/(ISSN)1469-1795/homepage/ForAuthors.html):

> Journal titles should be abbreviated in accordance with the Zoological Record Serial Sources, published annually by BIOSIS.

Is `Zoological Record Serial Sources` a citing style?

I am usually using Mendeley (and have little experience with citing style) but I can't find any citing style for `animal conservation` nor for `Zoological Record Serial Sources`.

Can you help me to find a way to automatically format my list of references to the correct citing style?

As an example. Can you cite [this paper](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/cobi.12372/full) to the right citing style

Comment: I would think that the editorial office can help you with that. Also my experience, albeit in a completely different field, is that the journal's editing will fix most citing style errors, as long as you provide complete information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks to me like ZRSS isn't a citation style, just a list of journals.  You can refer to that list to figure out how to abbreviate the name of a journal (e.g. *Animal Conservation* might be abbreviated as *Anim. Conserv.*) but it isn't supposed to show you how to format the rest of the citation.

If you keep reading right below there in the Guidelines for Authors, it contains more information about how to format citations, with several examples, and provides style files for EndNote and Reference Manager.  It is possible that someone else has written one for Mendeley, or you could do it.

If you need more detailed information than what is in the Guidelines, you will need to ask the editors.  If you look on the left side of the Guidelines page, there is a Contact link, which gives an email address for someone in the editorial office, who can be contacted with questions about "submitting a manuscript".